# Wordpress File name length error warning from template.php

Tags: php, wordpress, encryption

Getting this above error while posting Unicode content with long headings!

PHP Warning:  file_exists(): File name is longer than the maximum allowed path length on this platform (260) in

\httpdocs\wordpress/wp-content/themes/jagan/single-post-%e0%b0%aa%e0%b1%8d%e0%b0%b0%e0%b0%ae%e0%b0%be%e0%b0%a3%e0%b0%be%e0%b0%a8%e0%b0%bf%e0%b0%95%e0%b0%bf-%e0%b0%ae%e0%b1%81%e0%b0%82%e0%b0%a6%e0%b1%87-%e0%b0%ae%e0%b1%8a%e0%b0%a6%e0%b0%9f%e0%b0%bf.php in G:\PleskVhosts\httpdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\template.php on line 637

My Wordpress is windows installed with godaddy, not facing this issue with my local version running in wamp! getting this error only when clicking for full article that opens with single.php! i think as per template hierarchy its trying to fetch more specific single-post-with-actual-news-title.php which making the file name exceed windows file name limit?? is it wordpress issue or server issue? please suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you use telugu name for the file? try to use english itself. are you able to rename the file?

Comment: I didn't specifically named any files! when i post Telugu content and open it i am getting this error! i tried to see if i get the same error with shorter single word blog title post which didn't give any error! even if i post long English title i am getting the same error!

Comment: Ok. try to rename the slug of the page.

Comment: Oh great! no error after updating slug with English name! do we have to use slug name compulsory for Unicode content?